# TFS changes visible by some users but not all

Tags: tfs

This is probably some caching issue but I’m not sure how to fix it. We have TFS 2010 and a situation that some people with same level of permissions see the recent change but others do not (I’ve checked permissions 10X and I’m 100% sure they have exactly the same permission).

More specifically - this happened several times when I (admin account) added new iterations to one of the projects. Some people inside the project can see the change but others can’t.

Any ideas how to handle such issues?

Comment: If this still occurs, just give it a try to refresh the TeamExplorer of the user in Visual Studio. Some changes will not be updated automatically in VS, for example changing WITDs.

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question, but the users have restarted Visual Studio, yes?  Area path / iteration data is cached pretty aggressively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had same problem several times and we always managed to successfully solve it by deleting application caches on the TFS Server itself.

Just got to TFS installation folder on the TFS application tier and find folder

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web Services_tfs_data . Inside this folder you’ll find folder that looks like this “cde96d50-b143-4a28-b280-1cd24fa95525” – just go ahead and delete that folder. This is where TFS keeps its cached application data.